# Why class constructor being called for overloaded operator new?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am using c++11 (g++ v4.7.2)

I've overloaded operator new and operator delete for "Base" class. Apparently they should not call constructor/destructor upon call of new/delete because I've not implemented ctor/dtor call in overloaded new/delete. But the output is contrary to that

```
//Output of below program
Base new opnd.cpp 87
Base ctor
10
Base dtor
Base delete
```

Why ctor/dtor are being called for overloaded operator new/delete?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define NEW new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
#define DELETE delete

class Base
{
    public:
        Base():m_i(10){ cout << "Base ctor" << endl; }
        virtual ~Base(){ cout << "Base dtor" << endl; }

        void* operator new(size_t size, const char* file, int line) throw(std::bad_alloc);
        void operator delete(void *rawMem, size_t size);

        int geti(){ return m_i; }

    private:
        int m_i;
};

void* Base::operator new(size_t size, const char* file, int line) throw(std::bad_alloc)
{
    void *p;
    cout << "Base new " << file << " " << line << endl;

    //Handle 0 byte requests
    if(size == 0)
        size = 1;

    if(size != sizeof(Base))
    {
        return ::operator new(size);       // To handle new requests for derived classes
    }

    while(true)
    {
        p = malloc(size);

        if(p)
            return p;

        new_handler globalHandler = set_new_handler(0);
        set_new_handler(globalHandler);
        if(globalHandler) (*globalHandler)();
        else throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
}

void Base::operator delete(void *rawMem, size_t size)
{
    cout << "Base delete" << endl;
    if(rawMem == 0)
        return;

    if(size != sizeof(Base))
    {
        ::operator delete(rawMem);     //To handle delete requests for derived classes
        return;
    }

    free(rawMem);
}

int main()
{
   Base *b = NEW Base;
   cout << b->geti() << endl;
   DELETE b;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Overloaded `new()`/`delete` are called for memory mamagement only. The constructor/destructor calls are done independently.

Comment: `new`/`delete` are for allocation/deallocation, not initialization...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `operator new` function (be it the global one or a class-specific one) is not the entire implementation of a `new` expression. It's only the allocation function. When you write `new T` in your code, the following happens:

1. An appropriate allocation function named `operator new` is chosen and called to obtain space for the object.
2. `T`'s constructor is called on the space obtained from point 1.

This means there is no way to bypass constructor invocation by writing your own `operator new` - invoking the constructor is done by the language, not by the allocation function.

Answer (score 0):

'Operator new' and 'new Operator' are two distinct things. When we use new to create some object like

```
     MyClass* ca= new MyClass();
```

we are using the 'new Operator'. It does two things:

1. Calls 'Operator new' to allocate enough memory. It can be overloaded as you did.
2. Calls the constructor of the object to set initialization data.

These 2 steps will be executed no matter how the space is allocated. Hence after allocating memory using your overloaded 'Operator new', the constructor is called.